# iOS Swift Panframe framework sound but no video

Tags: ios, swift, 360-degrees

I am trying to create a 360 video app using the Panframe framework ([Panframe website](http://www.panframe.com)). This framework is created in Objective-C so I am also using the PanframeSDKWrapper found on GitHub to "swiftify" the Panframe framework ([PanframeSDKWrapper on GitHub](https://github.com/zmian/PanframeSDKWrapper)).

I have a Viewcontroller with the following code:

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, PanframeAssetObserver {

    var pfView: PanframeView!
    var pfAsset: PanframeAsset!

    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PlayButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var StopButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createView() -> Void {
        pfView = PanframeView(frame: view.bounds)
        pfView.autoresizingMask = ([.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight])
        // set the appropriate navigation mode PFView
        pfView.navigationMode = PanframeNavigationMode.Motion
        // set an optional blackspot image
        // add the view to the current stack of views
        self.view!.addSubview(pfView)
        self.view!.sendSubviewToBack(pfView)
        pfView.setViewMode(PanframeViewMode.Flat, andAspectRatio: 16.0 / 9.0)
        // Set some parameters
        self.resetViewParameters()
        // start rendering the view
        pfView.run()
    }

    func resetViewParameters() -> Void {
        pfView .setFieldOfView(75.0)
        // register the interface orientation with the PFView
        pfView .setInterfaceOrientation(self.interfaceOrientation)
        switch self.interfaceOrientation {
        case .Portrait, .PortraitUpsideDown:
            // Wider FOV which for portrait modes
            pfView .setFieldOfView(90.0)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func deleteView() -> Void {
        // Stop rendering the view
        pfView .halt()

        // Remove and destroy view
        pfView .removeFromSuperview()
        pfView = nil
    }

    func createAssetWithUrl(url: NSURL) -> Void {
        pfAsset = PanframeAsset(url: url, observer:self)

    }

    func deleteAsset() -> Void {

    }

    @IBAction func playButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
        createView()
        createAssetWithUrl(NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PANO1", ofType: "m4v")!))
        pfAsset.play()
    }

    @IBAction func stopButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
        pfAsset.stop()
    }

    func panframeAsset(asset: PanframeAsset, onPlayerTime time: CMTime) {

    }

    func panframeAsset(asset: PanframeAsset, onStatusMessage message: PanframeAssetMessage) {

    }

}
```

The PAN01.m4v is a sample video provided by the sample app (in Objective-C) of Panframe and is present in my resources.

When I build and run this app, I have no errors and I get sound from the video, but no picture. 
Any ideas why I have no video...?

Edit after Marius' comment: I am testing this on a real device (iPhone 5, iOS 9.2.1).

Comment: Are you running it in the Simulator?

Comment: No, I'm testing on a real device (iPhone 5). I know the simulator doesn't display video. I'll add this to the main question, seeing it is fairly important. Thanks!

Comment: i have the same problem? Have you figure that out ?

Comment: SInce I found no resolution, I tried a different SDK calld Kaboore. This one works so I'm currently working with that one.

Answer (score 0):

Its related to App-Transport security. If you look in the debug console, you should see some logs from the framework where it's trying to contact https://secure.panframe.com to validate the copy of the licence etc.

[image]

In your info.plist, set add App Transport Security settings to allow arbitrary loads for now.

If that does not work, it'll be related to the import statements in your bridging-header. The below should fix it.

```
#import "Panframe/PFAsset.h"
#import "Panframe/PFAssetObserver.h"
#import "Panframe/PFView.h"
#import "Panframe/PFObjectFactory.h"
#import "PanframeSDKWrapper.h"
```